# run a php script and upload a file by a form automatically?

Tags: php, html

I'm having problems automating the following process:

**What works:**

- i get values (by php script from mysql db)
- i store this values in variable or file (i.e. csv, multi lines)

exported values to csv looks like:

```
command=METER_READING delimiter=;
value 1;12/01/2019 23:59:00;42093.0000 
value 2;12/01/2019 23:59:00;4630.0000
```

(each value must be new line)

**The Problem:**

Unfortunately, the interface can only POST and she needs a file. Maybe there is a workaround so I use a variable. With the help of textarea, however, I had no success.

interface documentation:

```
iegUsername: your username
iegPassword: your password
iegImportFile: The UTF-8 encoded plain text import file. The file data may optionally be zipped.
```

The UTF-8 encoded plain text import file. The file data may optionally be zipped.

**So far** the whole thing works with the help of a manual click on Submit using this script:

```
  <form action="" method="post" id="fileForm" name="fileForm"               enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <b>Username: </b>
      <input type="text" id="iegUsername" name="iegUsername" value="myusername"><br />
      <b>Password: </b>
      <input type="password" id="iegPassword" name="iegPassword" value="mypassword"><br />
      <b>Content: </b>
      <input type="file" id="sourceFile" name="swpImportFile" value="" ><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload...">
```

As I said I could provide the values via variable or a location on the web server. How could one automate the form so that one does not have to select the file any more but values are transmitted automatically.

Note: I realize how to submit a form automatically (Javascript) and how to execute a php script automatically (CRON). For me it's just about how do I get automated values to the interface.

Many thx for suggestions.

Comment: If you need to automate this, then there should be no actual “form” involved in the first place. Go read up on how to make POST requests using PHP. cURL makes these things easier than assembling the necessary data structure manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I know about is that you can't. This is a huge security issue we are talking about. Inputs can't have a have a default value unless you upload a file manually and that is to avoid any malicious scripts that may run on your computer that'll upload your files other than the one that you have chosen.

Imagine that I know the name of the most important file on your computer, I can simply give it a value and let you download whatever you want and I can obtain the file that I want easily whether you wanted that or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to select a file and submit it automatically from the browser. This isn't possible for security reasons (you could suck files from a user's PC without their consent).

Depending on the POST destination, you could save your values in a variable and transmit its contents directly without a file upload.